# How do I export a list of all videos (Title, URL, and publication date) of a YouTube channel?

Tags: youtube, web-crawler, export

I am looking for a method that works for any YouTube channel. I have tried a combination of Scraper extension for Chrome and the free version of Screaming Frog SEO Spider. However, publication date is missing from the crawl.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Go to YouTube's Data API page and scroll down to the end of the page. In the section "Try it!" authorize your account to make API calls, into the part input box write contentDetails and into channelId input box write the ID of the channel you're interested in. Scroll down and hit execute.

If you don't know the channelId, go to this page, authorize the form again, into the part write again contentDetails and into forUsername input box write the username you're interested in. When you hit execute you'll get the ID of that particular username and you can now follow the steps in the first section.

Comment: Only works for 50 videos (there are 500 in the channel i'd to crawl) and the API response is not easily convertible to a simple csv list.